# Can custom feeds be used with SO?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange, feed

Is it possible to subscribe to custom question feeds on SO? For example, something like

> [Algorithm] OR [data-structures] BUTNOT [objective-c]

I do not know much about RSS feeds, and am wondering if that is possible. This would definitely be more useful than having a feed of certain tags alone. **I should be able to say that I do not want questions from particular tags.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, search [for something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23%2bjava%2boop?sort=newest&pagesize=50) with syntax like this:

```
[c#] or [java] not [oop]
```

...and click your browser's RSS icon. The contents of [the feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/c%23%2bjava%2boop) will be from the **newest** tab.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm+or+data-structures+-objective-c if you're really lazy. :P